# Java StringBuilder does not append strings

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I am using StringBuilder in my project. When I appen char everything is OK, but when I try to append string "8 (" or ") " or " ", it stays empty "".
Example (EDITED):

```
    int length = number.length();
    CharSequence sequence = number.subSequence(0,length);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(17);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if (Pattern.matches("^[\\d]$", String.valueOf(sequence.charAt(i)))){
            stringBuilder.append(sequence.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    sequence = stringBuilder.toString();
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(17);
    CharSequence s = "8 (";
    if (sequence.charAt(0) == 8 || sequence.charAt(0) == 7 || sequence.length() == 0){
        stringBuilder.append(s);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 11 && i < sequence.length(); i++){
        stringBuilder.append(sequence.charAt(i));
        if (i == 3){
            stringBuilder.append(") ");
        }
        if (i == 6 || i == 8){
            stringBuilder.append(' ');
        }
    }
    number.clear();
    number.clearSpans();
    number.append(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: Show us enough code to actually demonstrate the issue when run.

Comment: How are you deriving that sb = ""? `.toString()`?

Comment: Can not duplicate

Comment: Which output you want to achieve?

Comment: I can see it's current value while debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is

```
if (sequence.charAt(0) == 8 || sequence.charAt(0) == 7 ||
```

you need to compare to chars not ints

```
if (sequence.charAt(0) == '8' || etc
```